# Create path Box android SDK

Tags: android, box-api, boxapiv2

I'm trying to create file path with Box-v2 android API i found couple of workarounds but all of them is so slow. What is the proper way for creating a file path with android Box SDK for ex;

on user's box directory : "/User Folder/1/2/3" i would like to create nested directories as like that if it already doesn't exist.

I also want to create an App folder for my application on user's box folder like ;

"/Apps/MyAwsomeApp/Backup"

What is the proper way creating those paths.

Answer (score 0):

You would first check if the folder path exists. To do this, you would query the [Search API](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#searching-for-content) to see if the parent folder in the path exists. If it exists you would then call the [Get Folder's Items API](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#get-a-folders-items) to see if the next folder in the path exists. You would keep calling Get Folder's Items API until you confirm path exists or not.

If the folder path does not exist, then you would make calls serially to the [Create Folder API](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#create-a-new-folder) to build the folder path.

The [Box Android SDK](https://github.com/box/box-android-sdk) has a wrapper for these API calls.